# How update programmatically node entity with empty field_image?

Tags: 8, nodes, updating

i need to make an import from one mysql table in my base.

I create node with :

```
$value= array(
                'type' => strtolower($typeProduit),
                'field_1'=>"test",
                'title'=>"test",
                'body' => array(
                    'value' => "test",
                    'format' => 'full_html',
                ),
                'field_2'=>"",
                'field_3'=>"",
                'field_4'=>"",                
            );

 $nodeEntity=\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('node')
        ->create($value);

    $nodeEntity->save();
```

All node are create and if i have an image, i add it to my $value before save() :

```
$value['field_image_video']=array(
                    'target_id' => $fileImageVideo->id(),
                    'alt' => $catalogue->titreVideo,
                    'title' => $catalogue->titreVideo,
                );
```

if i have no image, i do nothing for this field.

I need to update some node programmatically after this first step.

And when i just try to change the title like this :

```
     $nodeEntityUpdate = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                    ->getStorage('node')                
                    ->load(273);

     $nodeEntityUpdate->title="blabla";
     $nodeEntityUpdate->save();
```

if node don"t have image field set, i got this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFileUri()

If node has image, update work.

How can i set my image_field to null ?

i try to set my image field like that on creation :

```
$value['field_image_video']=array();
```

But that didn't work.

this image field is set to unlimited values

Answer (score 0):

i got it in the update :

i set my image_field in the update:

```
  $nodeEntityUpdate = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                    ->getStorage('node')                
                    ->load(273);

     $nodeEntityUpdate->title="blabla";
     $nodeEntityUpdate->field_image_video =array();
     $nodeEntityUpdate->save();
```

I try to set this field in the create, but that change nothing.

As i can see, we need to set image field in the update if she is empty at the creation.

Comment: `$node->set($node->getEntityKey('label'), 'blabla')->set('field_image_video', NULL)->save();` or possibly `$node->get('field_image_video')->filter(TRUE)`.

Comment: yes but we need absolutly set the field_image_video ?